# Is generic template forwarding available in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've two generic functions:

```
findOne<Entity>(cls: ClassType<Entity>, id: number): Promise<Entity>;
plainToClass<T, V>(cls: ClassType<T>, plain: V, options?: ClassTransformOptions): T;
```

How can I forward the template from `findOne()` to `plainToClass()` like in this case?

```
findOne<Entity>(cls: ClassType<Entity>, id: number): Promise<Entity> {
  return new Promise<Entity>(resolve => {
    resolve(plainToClass(cls /* here */, this.electronService.ipcRenderer.sendSync('findOne', cls.name, id)));
  });
}
```

**Edit**

Here is a full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lqnedb

Comment: What do you mean by "forward the template"?  TypeScript's generics are not really templates as they exist in C++; there's a large enough mismatch that I'd suggest explicitly spelling out what you want to achieve without using template metaprogramming terminology.  Also, please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] as described by [ask].  Right now there are too many missing declarations and syntax errors.  (e.g., What is `ClassType`?  What is `ClassTransformOptions`?  What is `this.electronService.ipRenderer.sendSync()`?  Do you want `=>` instead of `=`?) Good luck!

Comment: I mean does this call `findOne(User, 4)` call `plainToClass(User /* <-- User here? */, ...)`? I forgot to precise that I'm totally new to TS. I'll add a full working example. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `new Promise(r => r(foo(x)))` calls `foo(x)`.  Have you tested it or tried to debug it?  The issue in your linked code is not that `plainToClass()` is not being called; it's that it doesn't know how to turn `createdAt` into a `Date`, as described [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#%D1%81onverting-date-strings-into-date-objects).

Comment: You got the point. I didn't know the plainToClass() issue with Date. Thanks!